# How to reset props when changing screens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have screens A -> B -> C. When I go back from screen C to B, I send back some props and set the state and display them, but when I go back to screen A from B I want to reset those props so the next time I go back to screen B those props aren't there.

Screen B:

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();
const [selectedData, setData] = useState([]);

//to listen for the props when coming back from screen C.
useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedData(route.params?.data[0]);
  }, [route]);

//Going back to screen A
const cancel = () => {
    setSelectedData([]);
    navigation.goBack(null);
  };
```

Comment: you can pass setDate from component A to component B and resetting state when moving from component B to component A. setData([]). You can read about prop drilling problem. You can also use React Context.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the main function to handle these situations and handle it.
for example:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
const handleStep = (incomingStep) => {
   if(condition){// do something base on the conditions}
     else { // do other things }
}
 return(<div> <Child handleSteps={handleStep} step= step /> </div>)
}
 
const Child = (handleSteps) => {
const onButtonClick = (step) => {handleSteps(step)};
return(
<div> 
<button onClick={() =>onButtonClick(1)}>1</button>
<button onClick={() =>onButtonClick(2)}>2</button>
<button onClick={() =>onButtonClick(3)}>3</button>
</div>
 )
}
```

I hope this help you